# Can't Figure Out Why This SQL Code Does Nothing

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, varchar

When I use this query:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `entry` (`id`, `name`) VALUES (1, 'bob');
```

This results in 1 row(s) affected.

Then I try

```
DELETE IGNORE FROM `entry` WHERE name='bob';
```

and I get 0 row(s) affected

Why doesn't that delete statement do anything? When I use a

```
DELETE IGNORE FROM `entry` WHERE id=1;
```

that results in 1 row(s) affected

---

The value type of name is varchar(255). Does that have something to do with it?

I'm trying to edit an existing database, so I can't remake the table.
**I just can't figure out why the delete WHERE name='bob' won't delete anything.**

#### Note:

When I query the table after inserting 1 and bob, the information is in there as follows

```
id, name

1   bob
```

Comment: Why are you using `IGNORE`? Could very well be masking the real problem

Comment: What mysql version?Do you have foreign keys?

Comment: @Martin Don't know my friend told me to.

Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor and reconnect.

That happens when I don't use ignore. I'll toggle the option in preferences and try again.

Comment: @Mihai MySQL 5.6 both on the database and mysql-workbench 
Foreign keys? I don't think so, my keyboard is US. the characterset in the name column is set to latin1

Comment: What does select * FROM `entry` WHERE name='bob' show ?

Comment: It was a wierd bug, my colleague tried using my delete code just now and it worked without a hitch!

Answer (score 0):

Is "entry" the actual table name?

Have you tried the statement without the ''?

```
DELETE IGNORE FROM entry WHERE name='bob';
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this was a wierd glitch because after disabling safe updated in edit -> preferences of mysql-workbench, the delete sql works properly.